# Cannot select text accurately by sliding with trackpad

Tags: touchpad

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on a Macbook pro early 2011 (with trackpad).

In Terminal, Firefox, Emacs... , extending text selection by sliding the pointer does not work.

The pointer gets stuck at some random point.

Double and triple clicking work normally.

How to select text of arbitrary length by sliding the pointer?

I have just checked with a normal mouse: it works.  May I conclude that the Mac trackpad is not compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: When the selection cannot be extended, it cannot be shrunk either, it can only be canceled by clicking.

Comment: Here is a possible starting point https://bill.harding.blog/2018/01/07/linux-with-a-macbook-touchpad-feel-pt-2.

Comment: The problem seems to be reduced by moving the pointer more carefully, so it might be related to pointer speed or acceleration.  Gnome desktop settings do not seem helpful.  The driver is bcm5974.  I believe that the settings are in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf.

Comment: All this is well documented for Archlinux https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration  https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/libinput.4.  I am trying options, for example, Left Handed.

Comment: The system has to decide when the selection has finished, depending on the motion of the pointer.  The difficulty for the user is to manage to "brake" on a width that is narrower than a single character.  In libinput, there is only one kinematic parameter, names "Accel Speed" that is just maximum speed and can be set graphically in Gnome > Settings > Mouse & Touchpad.  This can't be enough to achieve good precision.

Comment: I particular the velocity threshold should be adjustable.  This is consistent with the fact that the problem gets worse when decreasing pointer velocity (it also gets worse when increasing velocity because the brain is not fast enough to follow).

Comment: In Tweaks > Keyboard & Mouse is an additional setting for mouse: default is better for me.  Playing on this acceleration profile, speed, and left handed, I can almost make it.  I don't understant why I don't see acceleration profile in `xinput list-props`.